# Facebook like for android

Tags: android, webview

```
String htmlCodeGoesHere="<div id=\"fb-root\"></div>"+
"<script>(function(d, s, id) {"+
  "var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];"+
  "if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}"+
  "js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;"+
  "js.src = \"//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="xxxxxxxxxxx"\";"+
  "fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);"+
"}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>"+
"<div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx\" data-send=\"true\" data-width=\"450\" data-show-faces=\"true\"></div>";

WebView webview=new WebView(this);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            //webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webview.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            webview.setBackgroundColor(0xff2e2e2e);
            webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, htmlCodeGoesHere, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

this.addContentView(webview,params);
```

trying to add js and div to webview. showing a blank screen.

i am trying to do like functionality for android app. please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the output of your logcat and add something like this:

```
    /* WebChromeClient must be set BEFORE calling loadUrl! */
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            Log.e("js ", message);
            return false;
        }
    });/ // for debugging convenience.
```

to also log the javascript errors to logcat.